# Is there a way to detect first time access from eeprom

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega

**Environment**

I'm writing a small game for the `arduino` on the atmega328p, and I'm trying to keep a highscore by reading/writing from `eeprom` memory.

But I don't know how you can check if the data in `eeprom` is a correct highscore or some random data.

**Question**

Is there a way that you can detect if the data in `eeprom` is part of the program or manually reset it to a specific value in `Atmel Studio` / `Arduino IDE`?

Comment: you checked CRC? along with high score put CRC16/8 in EEPROM for the high score. after reading calculate the CRC from high score and compare with EEPROM stored CRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always try to write a small structure like this:

```
struct
{
uint32_t Signature;
uint32_t HighScore;
}EEPROMData;
```

you set signature to a known hardcoded value, set the highscore, and write the entire structure. On read, you would check the signature. It's highly unlikely it would be your value.

If you need even more insurance it's not just random data, you can do this:

```
struct
{
uint32_t Signature;
uint32_t HighScore;
uint32_t XORRResult;
}EEPROMData;
```

and also write the XOR result between signature and highscore. when you read it, you'd compare the xor from signature and highscore with XORResult. If it matches, then you wrote that data, wasn't random.

Answer (score 2):

If you programm your board you could erase the eeprom. This will mean that all bytes read as `0xFF`. If you store your highscore as BCD or ASCII (any representation that never uses 0xFF for your data) you can easily detect if the highscore is written the first time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

You should not write highscores to EEPROM, it should be treated as read-only

To answer your question: It probably is better to add some way of parity check to the highscore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit